# Apply SUM( where date between date1 and date2)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum

My table is currently looking like this:

```
+---------+---------------+------------+------------------+
| Segment |    Product    |  Pre_Date  |    ON_Prepaid    |
+---------+---------------+------------+------------------+
| RB      | 01. Auto Loan | 2020-01-01 | 10645976180.0000 |
| RB      | 01. Auto Loan | 2020-01-02 |  4489547174.0000 |
| RB      | 01. Auto Loan | 2020-01-03 |  1853117000.0000 |
| RB      | 01. Auto Loan | 2020-01-04 |  9350258448.0000 |
+---------+---------------+------------+------------------+
```

I'm trying to sum values of 'ON_Prepaid' over the course of 7 days, let's say from '2020-01-01' to '2020-01-07'.
Here is what I've tried

```
drop table if exists ##Prepay_summary_cash
    select *,
    [1W_Prepaid] = sum(ON_Prepaid) over (partition by SEGMENT, PRODUCT order by PRE_DATE rows between 1 following and 7 following), 
    [2W_Prepaid] = sum(ON_Prepaid) over (partition by SEGMENT, PRODUCT order by PRE_DATE rows between 8 following and 14 following),
    [3W_Prepaid] = sum(ON_Prepaid) over (partition by SEGMENT, PRODUCT order by PRE_DATE rows between 15 following and 21 following),
    [1M_Prepaid] = sum(ON_Prepaid) over (partition by SEGMENT, PRODUCT order by PRE_DATE rows between 22 following and 30 following),
    [1.5M_Prepaid] = sum(ON_Prepaid) over (partition by SEGMENT, PRODUCT order by PRE_DATE rows between 31 following and 45 following),
    [2M_Prepaid] = sum(ON_Prepaid) over (partition by SEGMENT, PRODUCT order by PRE_DATE rows between 46 following and 60 following),
    [3M_Prepaid] = sum(ON_Prepaid) over (partition by SEGMENT, PRODUCT order by PRE_DATE rows between 61 following and 90 following),
    [6M_Prepaid] = sum(ON_Prepaid) over (partition by SEGMENT, PRODUCT order by PRE_DATE rows between 91 following and 181 following)
    into ##Prepay_summary_cash 
    from ##Prepay1
```

Things should be fine if the dates are continuous; however, there are some missing days in 'Pre_Date' (you know banks don't work on Sundays, etc.).

So I'm trying to work on something like

```
[1W] = SUM(ON_Prepaid) over (where Pre_date between dateadd(d,1,Pre_date) and dateadd(d,7,Pre_date))
```

something like that. So if per se there's no record on 2020-01-05, the result should only sum the dates  on the 1,2,3,4,6,7 of Jan 2020, instead of 1,2,3,4,6,7,8 (8 because of "rows 7 following"). Or for example I have missing records over the span of 30 days or something, then all those 30 should be summed as 0s. So 45 days should return only the value of 15 days.
I've tried looking up all over the forum and the answers did not suffice. Can you guys please help me out? Or link me to a thread which the problem had already been solved.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you tried a conditional sum e.g.  `sum(case when {condition} then value else 0 end)`?

Comment: I did, sum(case when pre_date between dateadd(d,1,predate) and dateadd(d,7,predate) then ON_Prepaid else 0 end) only returns 0

Comment: If you're looking at evaluating the values (rather than the _number_ of rows) you may want to make your window functions use RANGE rather than ROWS e.g., https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2015/01/22/sql-server-windowing-functions-rows-vs-range/

Comment: That condition will never be met? 'pre_date' is never going within that range

Comment: Or is it as simple as partitioning by `datepart(week)`?

Comment: @seanb I've read the article, doesn't seem to work cuz' "range is only supported with unbounded and current row window frame delimiters".

Comment: @DaleK Yes the condition will never be met, bc I need values from date between date1 and date2 while "case when" only returns boolean-ish result. Or maybe I'm using it wrong? I'll try testing out datepart, but what happened when it's no longer a week? Like 1.5M or 45 days as I mentioned?
Thank you guys both, hit me up with any ideas that you guys could think of please I'm desperate lol

Comment: First please ensure your question contains a [mre] i.e. enough sample data to cover multiple ranges including the issue you mention, i.e. missing dates. Then also ensure you include your desired results to its clear to use what you wish to achieve. For a faster response include you sample data as DDL+DML (create temp table + insert into temp table) so we can copy and paste it out to test out possible solutions.

Comment: @alsogreenvbank "case when" only returns boolean-ish" - case when returns whatever you want it to return, other than Booleans (which aren't a thing in sqlserver)

Comment: @seanb always felt RANGE in sqls was a bit of a lame duck compared to eg oracle.. Unless there's some cool trick I've missed that would allow it to "sum 7 days hence from the current row's date" I think it's limited to "sum all rows around where the row has some column set the same as the current row" which, if the op's assertion that the question features nearly what is wanted is the case, means SQLS is a bit lacking in this regard

Comment: @caius - you and the OP are both probably right. I've only used RANGE in very rare occasions so I'm unaware of its limitations. That's why it was only a suggestion in a comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Things should be fine if the dates are continuous

Then make them continuous. Left join your real data (grouped up so it is one row per day) onto your calendar table (make one, or use a recursive cte to generate you a list of 360 dates from X hence) and your query will work out

```
WITH d as 
( 
  SELECT * 
  FROM 
    (
      SELECT * 
      FROM cal 
      CROSS JOIN 
      (SELECT DISTINCT segment s, product p FROM ##Prepay1) x
    ) c
    LEFT JOIN ##Prepay1 p 
    ON 
      c.d = p.pre_date AND 
      c.segment = p.segment AND 
      c.product = p.product
  WHERE 
    c.d BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-01-01' -- date range on c.d not c.pre_date
)

--use d.d/s/p not d.pre_date/segment/product in your query (sometimes the latter are null)
select *,
[1W_Prepaid] = sum(ON_Prepaid) over (partition by s, s order by d.d rows between 1 following and 7 following), 
...
```

CAL is just a table with a single column of dates, one per day, no time, extending for n thousand days into the past/future

Wish to note that months have variable number of days so 6M is a bit of a misnomer.. might be better to call the month ones 180D, 90D etc

Also want to point out that your query performs a per row division of your data into into groups. If you want to perform sums up to 180 days after the date of the row you need to pull a year's worth of data so that on row 180(June) you have the December data available to sum (dec being 6 months from June)

If you then want to restrict your query to only showing up to June (but including data summed from 6 months after June) you need to wrap it all again in a sub query. You cannot "where between jan and jun" in the query that does the sum over because where clauses are done before window clauses (doing so will remove the dec data before it is summed)

Some other databases make this easier, Oracle and Postgres spring to mind; they can perform sum in a range where the other rows values are within some distance of the current row's values. SQL server only usefully supports distancing based on a row's index rather than its values (the distancing-based-on-values support is limited to "rows that have the same value", rather than "rows that have values n higher or lower than the current row"). I suppose the requirement could be met with a cross apply, or a coordinated sub in the select, though I'd be careful to check the performance..

```
SELECT *, 
  (SELECT SUM(tt.a) FROM x tt WHERE t.x = tt.x AND tt.y = t.y AND tt.z BETWEEN DATEADD(d, 1, t.z) AND DATEADD(d, 7, t.z) AS 1W
FROM
  x t
```

Comment: I managed to create a "##CAL" table and yes, the problem became much simpler. However, the "SELECT d FROM ##CAL
      CROSS JOIN 
      (SELECT DISTINCT SEGMENT s, PRODUCT p FROM ##Prepay1) x" returned only a table with 1 column "d" containing dates range from 2020-01-01 to 2021-04-30 (I set the cut-off limits). Any suggestions on how did cross join fail to work?

Comment: wait never mind i changed from "select d from ##CAL" to "select * from ##CAL" and it worked. Not sure why though lol

Comment: That's a typo from me; your fix was correct. It is purely because though `cal CROSS JOIN (SELECT p, s FROM...)` is 3 columns (1 from cal and 2 from the distinct subquery), selecting only `d` then threw away the cross joined columns.. `SELECT *`, or `SELECT cal.d, x.p, x.s` would allow the date and product/segment to come through